Left outer join on multiple tables condition
I'm migrating my Delphi application from Firebird 2.5.9 to 5.0.
This query works good on Firebird 2.5.9, but throws an exception on Firebird 5.
select A.ca1, A.ca2, B.cb1, B.cb2
from A, B left outer join C on C.cc1 = B.cc1 and B.cc2 = A.ca3

The exception is Unknown column A.ca3. But A.ca3 is a column of table A. It seems I can't use tabla A in the condition of the left outer join for the second and third tables. It makes no sense.
Note: This query is a simplification of the real query in order to focus only on the problem, that is, I can't use columns of tabla A in the condition of the left outer join.

as far as I remember, mixing JOIN-styles is an extremely bad practice   select A.ca1, A.ca2, B.cb1, B.cb2
from A
join B on B.cc2 = A.ca3
left outer join C on C.cc1 = B.cc1

Also Firebird 5 has more strict rules about using table aliases: you cannot address a column by table name when alias has been set. That's why "simplification of the real query" is completely useless for diagnostic.

@user13964273 The real query isn't far from the one I put. I have only change the tables and fields names and remove the where condition. As you said, From FB 2, you cannot address a column by table name when alias has been set, but this is not the case because I didn't use alias for tables. But the same happens if you use it.

The rules where changed in Firebird 3.0 to conform to the SQL standard. You're using a SQL-89 implicit cross join combined with a SQL-92 explicit outer join. Following SQL rules, the SQL-92 outer join is evaluated before the SQL-89 cross join. It's basically equivalent to A cross join (B left outer join C on ...), so the ON clause condition cannot reference columns from table A. Firebird 2.5 and older did this wrong (and as a result could sometimes even produces "wrong" results, and sometimes the result could change depending on decisions made by the optimizer).
See Prohibit Edgy Mixing of Implicit/Explicit Joins and Support for Mixed-Syntax Joins is Gone in the Firebird 3.0 release notes.
You need to rewrite your query to use SQL-92 explicit joins all the way, or the condition B.cc2 = A.ca3 needs to be pushed down to the WHERE clause. The correct solution depends on which results need to be produced by the query.

Thanks for your detailed answer.
